# Replace multiple files with one file

Tags: clipboard

Imagine my directory looked like this:

```
./original.txt
./blah.1.txt
./blah.2.txt
[...]
./blah.999999.txt
```

I essentially want to replace every `blah.*` file with the contents of `original`.  My initial try was to do this:

```
$ cp original.txt blah.*
```

But I get:

``` cp: target ``blah.1.txt' is not a directory ```

Comment: I don't know much about `find`, but you could try executing commands through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one more option with `tee`:

```
cat original.txt | tee blah.*
```

And here's a test case that you can try at home under supervision from a responsible adult:

```
$ echo "rawr" | tee blah.{1..99}.txt
rawr

$ ls
blah.10.txt  blah.26.txt  blah.41.txt  blah.57.txt  blah.72.txt  blah.88.txt
blah.11.txt  blah.27.txt  blah.42.txt  blah.58.txt  blah.73.txt  blah.89.txt
blah.12.txt  blah.28.txt  blah.43.txt  blah.59.txt  blah.74.txt  blah.8.txt
blah.13.txt  blah.29.txt  blah.44.txt  blah.5.txt   blah.75.txt  blah.90.txt
blah.14.txt  blah.2.txt   blah.45.txt  blah.60.txt  blah.76.txt  blah.91.txt
blah.15.txt  blah.30.txt  blah.46.txt  blah.61.txt  blah.77.txt  blah.92.txt
blah.16.txt  blah.31.txt  blah.47.txt  blah.62.txt  blah.78.txt  blah.93.txt
blah.17.txt  blah.32.txt  blah.48.txt  blah.63.txt  blah.79.txt  blah.94.txt
blah.18.txt  blah.33.txt  blah.49.txt  blah.64.txt  blah.7.txt   blah.95.txt
blah.19.txt  blah.34.txt  blah.4.txt   blah.65.txt  blah.80.txt  blah.96.txt
blah.1.txt   blah.35.txt  blah.50.txt  blah.66.txt  blah.81.txt  blah.97.txt
blah.20.txt  blah.36.txt  blah.51.txt  blah.67.txt  blah.82.txt  blah.98.txt
blah.21.txt  blah.37.txt  blah.52.txt  blah.68.txt  blah.83.txt  blah.99.txt
blah.22.txt  blah.38.txt  blah.53.txt  blah.69.txt  blah.84.txt  blah.9.txt
blah.23.txt  blah.39.txt  blah.54.txt  blah.6.txt   blah.85.txt
blah.24.txt  blah.3.txt   blah.55.txt  blah.70.txt  blah.86.txt
blah.25.txt  blah.40.txt  blah.56.txt  blah.71.txt  blah.87.txt

$ cat blah.67.txt 
rawr

$ echo "hooray" > original.txt

$ cat original.txt | tee blah.*.txt
hooray

$ cat blah.67.txt 
hooray
```

Comment: `And here's a test case that you can try at home under supervision from a responsible adult` -- I don't think I saw this before. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Use bash's `for` (assuming you're using bash):

```
for file in blah.*.txt; do
    cp original.txt "$file"
done
```

Comment: Yeah that's my bad. I thought something else was causing the initial error.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, avoiding for-loops and keeping things in one line:

```
ls blah.* | xargs -n 1 cp original
```

---

You are getting `cp: target blah.1.txt is not a directory` in your original attempt, because cp'ing multiple files assumes moving all of them to the directory provided as the last argument. It's simply wrong syntax. Quoting `man cp`:

```
SYNOPSIS
       cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
       cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
       cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

DESCRIPTION
       Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
```

Solely using `cp` won't help you out. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195655/how-to-copy-a-file-to-multiple-directories-using-the-gnu-cp-command).

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
for i in `ls *.txt`; do cat original > $i; done
```

where original is the text file. `cat` just dumps the contents and the `>` pipes the contents into a new file represented by `$i` (expanded from the list returned by the `ls *.txt` command)

Note this will completely overwrite those files so you may want to put back them up first in another directory.  This will do it for anything with a .txt extension too (including the original file if it is a .txt extension) so you may want to rename things or use a better convention (e.g. blah* instead of *.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option using `find`:

```
find ./ -name 'blah.*.txt' -exec cp original.txt {} \;
```

You're asking `find` to start in the current directory and find files whose name matches the pattern (in quotes, to avoid the shell expanding it and letting find do the pattern-expansion), and for each file found, execute the command between `-exec` and `\;`. In this command, `{}` is replaced by the found file's name.

Look at this answer for a good deal of information on using `find` effectively:

[How can I use find command more efficiently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153172/how-can-i-use-find-command-more-efficiently)