# cron php command causes CIFS NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: 14.04, mount, php, cron, cifs

For the past day, every half hour or so, /var/log/syslog gets this burst within one second:

```
CRON[23914]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -x /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean /var/lib/php5 $(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime))
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
Status code returned 0xc000006d NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -13
```

The script `/etc/cron.d/php5` contains that first line, with a comment " Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes".  A bit more investigation shows that it's tidying up /var/lib/php5 (which is quite bare; this host doesn't use php).

1. Why could the 4 error messages have suddenly started to appear? Removing old files shouldn't cause anything to try to mount a CIFS share.
2. What's a clean way to stop `/etc/cron.d/php5` from running?  Uninstall php completely?  (Editing the script is like telling the roomba to keep mopping up the bathroom floor, instead of phoning the plumber.)

Possibly related:

- [What does this (root) CMD line in system.log mean? Why is it there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433333/what-does-this-root-cmd-line-in-system-log-mean-why-is-it-there)
- https://github.com/chriswayg/apache-php/issues/1

Comment: I think the first line is indicating success from the `php5` session cleaner and the rest is from another error. You could update that `cron` to output to a different log file to be sure though. If you don't need `php5`, why not uninstall it?

Comment: I now doubt that php causes the 4 errors, despite the suspiciously close timing.  Nowhere in `/etc/cron*/*` does the string "mount" occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely not caused by PHP5 and instead caused by a samba setup.  Check to see if you have a share in your /etc/fstab which might be attempting an SMB mount to a windows volume/server on a 30min refresh.  My guess is you are seeing two different errors.  Session garbage collection on PHP would not cause the NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE unless you moved your session storage to a Samba-mounted share.

You could determine your session path with this:

`php -i|grep -i session.save_path`

However, the error you outlined is coming from something else.

Comment: That command returned `/var/lib/php5`, supporting the idea that the error isn't caused by php.  When I dug around /etc/fstab and commented out some old unneeded shares, then the errors stopped, and haven't come back in several hours.

Comment: beautiful, glad it worked!