# Wildcard: return source path

Tags: bash, mv, wildcards

I'm trying to rename every `access.log.gz` file (note: exact filename, not "beginning with" or "containing") found in `/home/*/logs` to `date-access.log.gz` in the same folder.

```
for file in /home/*/logs/access.log.gz
do
   mv -v "$file" /home/*/logs/old/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`"-access.log.gz"
done
```

Of course I'm getting `/home/*/logs/2014-09-08-access.log.gz - No such file or directory`. How can I call the `*` paths back? Each file should be renamed and moved to /old/ subdir of the source folder. I tried with

```
mv -v "$file" /home/`$1`/logs/old/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`"-access.log.gz"
```

... but didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` ([How can I use find command more efficiently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153172/how-can-i-use-find-command-more-efficiently)).

```
find /home/ -ipath */logs/access.log.gz
```

That should find all the files you're interested in, and print them. You could plug that into your script, but it's probably easier to let  `find` do all the hard work.

```
find /home/ -ipath */logs/access.log.gz -execdir mv "{}" "old/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`-access.log.gz" \;
```

The features of `find` we're using here are:

- `-ipath` matches patterns in the found filenames. You could also use `-name` if you knew for sure there's only one access.log.gz file in each subpath (`-name access.log.gz`).
- `-execdir` executes the given command on each found file, from the subdirectory containing the matched file. This is equivalent to doing `cd` to where each file is and then running the command there. In this case it saves a lot of path manipulation logic. The found file is substituted for {}. Notice also that "old" is given as a relative path (as you said that `old/` exists in `logs/`)

Answer (score 1):

Simply dissect and re-assemble `$file` as you iterate over the matching files: `${file%/*}` gives you $file with everything after the last `/` removed, and `${file##*/}` gives you $file with everything before the last `/` removed; taken together `${file%/*}/old/$date-${file##*/}` will give you the "new" filename corresponding to `$file`.

Presumably the date won't change in the course of running your script, so there's no point in invoking `date` for each and every file; rather, store the date in a variable once, and then use that during the loop: `date=$(date '+%G-%m-%d')`. (Note that modern scripts should use `$(...)` rather than backticks. Also note that `%` is not a "special" character and so doesn't need quoting or escaping, though as a matter of good practice the whole format string should be quoted.)

If you have a new version of Bash, you can avoid the subshell entirely by using `printf -v date '%(%G-%m-%d)T' -1` instead.

You might also find it useful to use `shopt -s globstar` so that you can search to arbitrary depth in the directories, and `shopt -s nullglob` so that unmatched glob (wildcard) expand to "nothing" instead of the original glob pattern.

Putting these all together we get:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
date=$( date '+%G-%m-%d' )
for file in /home/*/logs/**/access.log.gz
do
    target=${file%/*}/old/$date-${file##*/}
    mv -vi "$file" "$target"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have [zsh](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zsh) installed, use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv). In a script:

```
#!/bin/zsh
autoload zmv
zmv '/home/*/logs/access.log.gz' '$f:h/`date +\%G-\%m-\%d`-$f:t'
```

On the zsh command line, put `autoload zmv` in your `~/.zshrc` and run that last line at the command prompt.