# How to find files that contains some Cyrillic word?

Tags: search

I want to search for files that contains some Cyrillic word (example in .MS word .doc files) with GUI. I tried gnome-search-tool but it does not work with Cyrillic. It say: `no files found`

How should I proceed?

Comment: The problem is rather not that gnome-search-tool does not know cyrillic, but rather that it does not decode MS word files into text to search in them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `gnome-search-tool` to look for `.txt` or `.rtf` files containing any Unicode characters (including Cyrillic ), this just works.  *However* your example of `.doc` files is a bad one as *these are binary files* coming from a program that uses *compression* to store the text that you see on the screen in a proprietary format on disk, so there the `gnome-search-tool` *does not* work.

The workaround is to convert all your `.doc` files to `.rtf` and then you can open them *and* search them

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have gnome-search-tool, but every *nix system has command line, and there are already tools there for finding files with particular strings inside them or in the names. So open the gnome-terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and lets get started.

Best suggestion is probably try to remember where you've placed the file in the first place? what directory ? I bet 99%  that it must be somewhere in your home folder. Remembering at least approximate location will aid the programs and commands discussed here in doing their job.

**N.B:** I strongly suggest you read man pages for grep, egrep, find, [ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FindingFiles), other [askubuntu posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153172/how-can-i-use-find-command-more-efficiently) as well as this [cyberciti article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-search-find-file-for-text-string/)

**Searching for files with cyrilic word in a name**

If you know at least some command line, chances are you're probably familiar with command like `ls` , which lists the contents of a directory you're in. Now, what will happen if you do `ls *` ? This will list contents of directory with its sub-directories, and their contents too. What you can do now is

`ls * | grep -i place-word-in-cyrylic here`

What happens here? You're getting all the contents of your home directory plus their subdirectories, and then filtering with grep by that word, where -i means dont be case sensitive. 
For instance,
[image]

Here I am looking for file `HelloПриветИзКосмосаWorld` which we did find. But it doesn't tell me where it is. `find` command solves the problem. Copy the name of the file you got and give it to `find`. Also , it might be a good idea to add -print option to `find`, because sometimes it doesn't print anything.

Side note: You can copy and paste everything by right clicking.

**Searching for strings within files**

This one is even easier with `grep "string" /path/to/your/folder` . Since picture is worth 1000 words, I'll just post a screenshot

[image]